# Characteristic Function of Inverse Gaussian Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, normal-distribution

The pdf of Inverse  Gaussian distribution, IG$(\mu,\lambda)$, is :

$$p_X(x)=\sqrt\frac{\lambda}{2\pi x^3}\exp\left[\frac{-\lambda}{2\mu^2x}(x-\mu)^2\right];\quad x>0,\lambda,\mu>0$$

I have to compute the Characteristic Function, $\phi_X(t)$.

$$\phi_X(t)=\mathbb E(e^{itX})=\int_0^\infty e^{itx}\sqrt\frac{\lambda}{2\pi x^3}\exp\left[\frac{-\lambda}{2\mu^2x}(x-\mu)^2\right] \, dx$$

I tried to fall it under Gamma function.

$$\phi_X(t)=\sqrt\frac{\lambda}{2\pi}e^{\lambda/\mu}\int_0^\infty x^{\frac{-3}{2}}\exp\left[-\left(\frac{\lambda}{2\mu^2}+\frac{\lambda}{2x^2}-it\right)x\right]dx$$

$$ = \sqrt\frac{\lambda}{2\pi}e^{\lambda/\mu}\int_0^\infty x^{\frac{-3}{2}}\exp\left[\left(it-\frac{\lambda}{2\mu^2}\right)x-\frac{\lambda}{2x}\right]dx  $$

Comment: Really very urgent.

Comment: Why is it urgent?

Comment: @harry The answer is readily available at wikipedia: [wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution)

Comment: @StefanHansen My examination is knocking at the door

Comment: @Sasha I have to compute it step by step. The result is also available in the book.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a computer algebra system to do the manual work for you? 
Given random variable $X\sim \operatorname{InverseGaussian}(\mu, \lambda)$ with pdf $f(x)$:

[image]

... the expectation you seek is simply:

[image]

where `Expect` is a function from the `mathStatica` add-on to *Mathematica* (I am one of the authors of the former). There are other packages for Maple etc (I am not an author of that package) that can solve these sorts of problems too, and then you can solve them yourself just as easily.

Comment: It is really excellent. But for my exam i need to do it manually.

Comment: Methinks, then, perhaps, the tags that you have added (probability, statistics, prob distributions, normal distribution) are not the appropriate ones for that which you seek. What you really seek is how to integrate something step-by-step.

Comment: @wolfies: It is worth noting that you are a coauthor of mathStatica.

Answer (score 1):

So what you actually have is called a generalised inverse Gaussian distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse_Gaussian_distribution)

$$ \sqrt\frac{\lambda}{2\pi}e^{\lambda/\mu}\int_0^\infty x^{\frac{-3}{2}}\exp\left[\left(it-\frac{\lambda}{2\mu^2}\right)x-\frac{\lambda}{2x}\right]dx  \\
=C\int_0^\infty x^{-\frac{1}{2}-1}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(\frac{\lambda}{\mu^2}-2it\right)x+\frac{\lambda}{x}\right)\right)dx $$

Using the normalising constant of a generalised inverse Gaussian and the constants, $C=\sqrt\frac{\lambda}{2\pi}e^{\lambda/\mu}$, $~a=\frac{\lambda}{\mu^2}-2it$,  $~b=\lambda$, $~p=-\frac{1}{2}$ above is:

$$C\frac{2\mathcal{K}_p(\sqrt{ab})}{(a/b)^{p/2}}\int_0^\infty \frac{(a/b)^{p/2}}{2\mathcal{K}_p(\sqrt{ab})}x^{p-1}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(ax+\frac{b}{x}\right)\right)dx\\
=C\frac{2\mathcal{K}_p(\sqrt{ab})}{(a/b)^{p/2}}=\sqrt\frac{\lambda}{2\pi}e^{\lambda/\mu}\frac{2\mathcal{K}_{1/2}(\sqrt{ab})}{(a/b)^{1/4}}$$

Where $\mathcal{K}_p$ is the modified besssel function of the second kind, and is invariant to positive or negative indeces, furthermore $\mathcal{K}_{1/2}(u)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2u}}\exp(-u)$

I will let you complete the rest